# How to scale <image> svgs with their parent svg containers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

Previously, I had the following code for my main SVG component, composed of both interactive and non-interactive elements.

```
<div>
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1080 1920" image="100%" height="100%">
    <g id="INTERACTIVE_SVG_ELEMENT_A">...</svg>
    <g id="INTERACTIVE_SVG_ELEMENT_B">...</svg>
    <g id="NON_INTERACTIVE_SVG_ELEMENTS_1">...</svg>
    ...
    <g id="NON_INTERACTIVE_SVG_ELEMENTS_100">...</svg>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Following [this tip](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/improving-svg-rendering-performance#inline-svg-object-img-or-background-image-15), I decided to wrap all non-interactive svg elements into an svg file `non-interactive.svg`, which contains the following:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1080 1920">
  <g id="NON_INTERACTIVE_SVG_ELEMENTS_1">...</svg>
  ...
  <g id="NON_INTERACTIVE_SVG_ELEMENTS_100">...</svg>
</svg>
```

With this, I thought I could optimize my original main SVG component to the following:

```
<div>
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1080 1920" image="100%" height="100%">
    <g id="INTERACTIVE_SVG_ELEMENT_A">...</svg>
    <g id="INTERACTIVE_SVG_ELEMENT_B">...</svg>
    <image href="/non-interactive.svg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The problem, however, is that the non-interactive SVG components no longer scale the same way as the parent view box. Essentially, I want to achieve the same effect of having the non-interactive and interactive SVG components overlapping each other and scaling the exact same way. Is this possible with the above format?

Comment: Have you tried set width and height, and not use %, % is CSS , and I believe svgs want specific px values..

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good or accurate tip. Maybe just go back to what you were doing.